# Serialize property even empty

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How can I tell to the XmlSerializer to serialize a string property that is empty?

```
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i did not try it, but "IsNullable" of XmlElementAttribute maybe helps with strings

Comment: just to be sure: you've set IsNullable to false?